# How could I filter Youtube videos for include only elements with specific lenght duration?

Tags: php, api, video, youtube

From Youtube API data, to filter videos by lenght, you're suggesting to use the parameter `duration` in this way:

```
short – Only include videos that are less than four minutes long.
medium – Only include videos that are between four and 20 minutes long (inclusive).
long – Only include videos longer than 20 minutes
```

Is there a different way to use the Youtube API to filter videos for a specific time instead? Let's say include all elements between 2 min. and 10 min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use avconv library for split video from any url.

https://libav.org/avconv.html